# Image button click event in datalist not firing

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have an imagebutton which is in a datalist. Onclick, the event for the image button is not firing. How can I get it to fire?

```
<asp:DataList ID="datalistsoru" runat="server" 
        BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" >
        <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"
        OnClick="ImageButton1_Click"  ImageUrl="~/resimler/yukariok.jpg" ToolTip="Oyu Arttır" />
 </ItemTemplate>
```

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to prevent the event, or prevent the redirect?

Comment: Did you have `AutoEventWireup="true"` at `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" ... %>`?

Comment: yes It is so <%@ Page  Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Sablon.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Cevaplar.aspx.cs" Inherits="Cevaplar"  %>

Comment: The code you posted above is working. The error must be from somewhere else. Please post the rest of the code.

Comment: @Murat Akarsu - Win is right, the code is working.

Comment: I will round the bend how works it.it doesnt work mine

Comment: Ok it works when I open a new page which has form tag but my page is above has no form tag because I use masterpage.So it doesnt work please help